# The server responded with a status of 500 AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript function which should redirect me to

`http://localhost:8888/ID OF A PRODUCT/add-to-cart".`

But instead I got this:

`http://localhost:8888/undefined/add-to-cart".`

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
        var productId = $(this).find('.indexImg').attr('id');

        $.ajax(productId+"/add-to-cart",
        {

        });
    });
```

`<img class="indexImg" src="{{$product->image}}" id="{{$product->id}}">`

Can someone help me to get ID of a product ?

HTML:

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box-product">
            <div class="img-wrapper item">
                <a href="/product/{{$product->id}}/{{$product->slug}}">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="/product/{{$product->id}}/{{$product->slug}}" style="margin-bottom: 0px; border: none;"> 
                    <img class="indexImg" src="{{$product->image}}" id="{{$product->id}}">
                    </a>
                </a>
            <div class="tags">
            @if($product->discount > 0)
                <span class="label-tags"><span class="label label-danger">Išpardavimas</span></span>
            @endif    
                <span class="label-tags"><span class="label label-info">Nauja</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart add-to-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: error itself describing the reason. `undefined`. It mean `productId` is empty.

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is you go check the server’s error logs …

Comment: @urfusion But its not empty. It shows 86

Comment: write `console.log(productId);` after the `var productId = $(this).find('.indexImg').attr('id');` and check in console what you get.

Comment: It says `undefined` but when I inspect element I see that `id` is set to 86

Comment: can you paste your `html`

Comment: maybe you are reading the id wrong?

Comment: @urfusion I've updated my question

Comment: where is `.add-to-cart`?

Comment: @urfusion Edited again

Comment: try `<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart add-to-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white"  id="{{$product->id}}"></i>` and get `$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Works @urfsion ty

Comment: @feknaz : cool. I am writing answer for you, you may accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing 
Change

`<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart add-to-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white"></i>`

With

`<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart add-to-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white" id="{{$product->id}}"></i>`

and get by

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

So the code will be

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
        var productId =  $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax(productId+"/add-to-cart",
        {

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (event) {
        var productId = event.target.id;

        $.ajax(productId+"/add-to-cart",
        {

        });
    });
```

Comment: Its not showing the `id` or even `undefined`. It's shows nothing

Comment: What does console.log(event.target.id) says? Also check console.log(event.target), maybe your element doesn't have id and that's it.

Comment: an explanation as to why that would work helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

.find is try to find inside current element u need to go up then find indexImg

```
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
       var productId = $(this).parents('.box-product').find('.indexImg').attr('id');

       $.ajax(productId+"/add-to-cart",
       {

       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to get product ID based on DOM is incorrect. The jQuery .find() method looks for specified elements within the elements, i.e. its descendants. If you look at the HTML, you'll see that the `div` elements containing the `add-to-cart` button and the image whose id attribute you are trying to fetch are on the same level.

So you've got to change the way you are traversing to reach the `id` attribute of the `<img>` tag.

`var productId = $(this).closest('.box-product').find('.indexImg').attr('id');`